# XSLT: replace text between two nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm new at XSLT, and I would like to know if there is a function to perform the following task:

Imagine I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<text> blabla ? blabl ?  abla ?  </text>
```

I would like to apply a template to replace each "?" with "." when I transform my xml. 
Here is the xslt template i would like to have:

```
<xsl:template match="text">
        <xsl:replace="? with ."/> //I know it doesn't work, I just want to know if there is a function to perform something like this
  </xsl:template>
```

Is it possible?
 I learned with the w3school tutorial, and there is nothing there to perform this task.(It's a very basic tutorial) Can you advise me a good tutorial or book to learn xsl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. There are several generic solutions to do string replacement with XSLT here on StackOverflow, so I will not write another one and instead just link to some of them.

- [How to remove particular characters from a string using XSLT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153304/how-to-remove-particular-characters-from-a-string-using-xslt)
- [Find and Replace with Unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31366/xslt-find-and-replace-with-unique)
- [xslt1.0 replace is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426073/xslt1-0-replace-is-not-working)
- [XSLT multiple replacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117358/xslt-multiple-replacing)
- there are [more](http://www.google.com/?q=xslt%20string%20replace%20site:stackoverflow.com)

Instead of voting for this answer, please vote for the one that you ended up using/that helped you most.

Answer (score 2):

[translate function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256119.aspx)

Comment: Will work for that specific case, but I would not be surprised if the OP had something more complex in mind than replacing a single character.